# get empty request while posting

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, reactjs, django-views

I was just trying to understand the connection between ajax request with django views but i am getting an error while toggling the switch on and off. I have a simple switch which is used for on and off. When user on the switch, django view should get on value through request.post but it is not able to get the data from my ajax request. What have i missed or done wrong?

```
def toggle(request):
    status = {}
    if request.method=="POST":
        print('request', request.POST.get('toggle', ''))
        status['message'] = 'success'
    else:
        status['message'] = 'error'
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(status), content_type="application/json")
```

**frontendForm**

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { toggled: true };
    }

    getChildContext() {
      return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme(Style) };
    }

    handleToggle = (event) => {
        // console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-isToggled'));
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            toggled: !this.state.toggled
        });
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/toggle/',
            headers: {
              'X-CSRFToken': CSRF_TOKEN,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            data:{
                toggle:this.state.toggled
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="automation" style={automationStyle}>
                <form>
                    <Card style={{ padding: '5em' }}>
                        <CardHeader
                            title="Turn on/off light"
                            titleStyle={{fontSize: '24px'}}
                        />
                        <CardText>
                        <Toggle
                          label="On/Off"
                          id="toggle"
                          onToggle={this.handleToggle}
                          data-isToggled={this.state.toggled}
                          toggled={this.state.toggled}
                          labelStyle={{ fontSize: '24px' }}
                          labelPosition="right"
                          className="toggle"
                        />
                        </CardText>
                    </Card>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting JSON, but request.POST will only contain form encoded data.

You have a couple of options. The first is to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type, then you can use `request.POST`.

Alternatively, you can get the json string from `request.body` and deserialise it.

```
data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
toggle = data.get('toggle', '')
```

Comment: request.body worked for me. Thanks for your support.